# Por que no me sale el codigo?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un curso de python y estamos dando documentación y pruebas con Doctest. Me sale que no salio bien el código pero al instructor si le salio. En que me equivoque en el código?

Este es el código:

```py
import math

def raizCuadrada(lista):
    
    """   
    >>> lista=[]
    >>> for i in [4, -9, 16]:
    ...     lista.append(i)
    >>> raizCuadrada(lista)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       ...
    ValueError: math domain error    
    """
    
    return [math.sqrt(n) for n in lista]

import doctest
doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: probá eliminando la última linea:  '''

Comment: Te sobran espacios al final de `domain error`.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Mil gracias! Nunca pensé que eso hiba a afectar en la salida del código.

Answer (score 0):

en primer lugar me gustaría decirte que es una buena practica escribir según el pep 8 y por convención las funciones es mejor separarlas con `_` que escribirla con mayúscula pero bueno sólo es una buena practica, he visto que en el test pusiste raíz negativa, lo mejor es una excepción en este caso y luego poner varios casos más. no se si realmente es esto lo que necesitas o es algo específico del error. Un saludo y cualquier cosa puedes decirnos

```
import math
import doctest

def raiz_cuadrada(lista):

    """   
    >>> raiz_cuadrada([4, 9, 16])
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    >>> raiz_cuadrada([4, -9, 16])
    Los números negativos no tienen raíces cuadradas

    """
    try:
      print([math.sqrt(n) for n in lista])
    except ValueError:
      print('Los números negativos no tienen raíces cuadradas')
doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Te lo vuelvo a decir otra vez, agrega una explicación a tu respuesta. Por eso te he votado en contra

Comment: es que ha veces no me sale has despues de publicar, perdon.

Comment: por eso puedes editar tu respuesta, la puedes volver a editar si quieres

Comment: ok, estaré más atento. Un saludo